# Physics problem, stuck in algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I end up with the equations;

$$u=u_1' \cos(a)+u_2' \cos(b)$$
$$u_1' \sin(a)=u_2' \sin(b)$$
$$u^2=u_1'^2+u_2'^2$$

I have to show that $$a+b=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$x'$ isn't the derivative of $x$, it's a convenient way not to mix variables in physics.

I have no approach. Tried substituting the trigonometrics as $x,y$ etc but it became more confusing and I couldn't do any trig identities easily.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is this an elastic scattering problem?

Comment: I have no idea what's the translation in english, sorry. And for you physics guys out there, if you guess the problem, yes there is another way to prove it with physics but I want to see the mathematical-based solution too.

Comment: "Elastic scattering" just means "stuff colliding without losing energy", i.e. momentum and energy are both conserved.

Comment: Then yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

I did some changes in variable names, for brevity. Namely $u_1' = x, u_2' = y$

### Solution

$$
u = x \cos a + y \cos b \\
x \sin a = y \sin b \\
u^2 = x^2 + y^2
$$
Square first equation and use second equation
$$
u^2 = x^2(1 - \sin^2 a) + y^2 (1 - \sin^2 b) + 2xy \cos a \cos b = x^2 + y^2 - 2x^2 \sin^2 a + 2xy \cos a \cos b
$$
Now use third equation, so
$$
x \sin^2 a = y \cos a \cos b \implies y \sin a \sin b = y \cos a \cos b \implies \tan a = \cot b \ = \tan (\pi/2 - b)
$$
Within the range of periodicity it means that 
$$
a + b = \frac \pi 2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=u_1' , y=u_2'$.

$$u=x \cos a+y \cos b \tag{1}$$
$$0=x \sin a-y \sin b \tag{2}$$
$$u^2=x^2+y^2 \tag{3}$$

$(1)^2+(2)^2 \implies $

$$u^2=x^2+y^2+2xy\cos (a+b) \tag{4}$$

From (4) and (3) we have:

$$ xy\cos (a+b)=0 \tag{5}$$

If $x\not =0$ and $y\not =0$, then $a+b=\pm k \pi+\pi/2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: square the first identity, susbtitute in the third identity, and remember

$$ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1 $$

and

$$\cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b$$

Comment: What do you mean by identities?

Comment: @user148432 the three equations listed in your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vector-based approach. Your first two equations are saying that the (velocity) vectors $\mathbf{u}',\mathbf{u}_1',\mathbf{u}_2'$ satisfy $\mathbf{u}'=\mathbf{u}_1'+\mathbf{u}_2'$ (eqs. 1 and 2 express vector components with $\mathbf{u}'$ along the $x$-axis.) Then $$u'^2=|\mathbf{u}'|^2=|\mathbf{u}_1'+\mathbf{u}_2'|^2=u_1'^2+2\mathbf{u}_1'\cdot \mathbf{u}_2'+u_2^2=u_1'^2+2u_1 u_2 \cos\theta+u_2'^2$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two scattered particles. But your third equation will then only be satisfied if $\cos\theta=0$ which in this context only works if $\theta=\pi/2$---and what is $\theta$ in terms of $a$ & $b$?